# Unity gives "Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected" error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

Getting two errors here, but I'm pretty sure they're dependent upon each other:

> Assets\Course Library\Scripts\PlayerController.cs(9,16): error CS1513: `}` expected
>
> Assets\Course Library\Scripts\PlayerController.cs(42,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

It doesn't really make any sense to me. I'm certain I formatted it correctly, and that the syntax is correct. Anytime I make any changes to the line of code where the errors are, it only throws more errors at me.

I thought there was a possibility that there was only one mistake somewhere in the code that causing a compound reaction, but I couldn't find anything wrong.

Could someone with more knowledge about Unity please explain to me what it is I'm doing wrong?

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {
        public float tank = GameObject.Find("tank").transform.localPosition.x;
    }

    public float horizontalInput;
    public float speed = 5;
    public float xRange = 20;
    public float zRange = 30;
    public float zRange2 = -8;
    public float turnSpeed = 20;
    public float forwardInput;

    void Update()
    {
        if (transform.position.x < -xRange){
            transform.position = new Vector3(-xRange, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }
        if (transform.position.x > xRange){
            transform.position = new Vector3(xRange, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }
        if (transform.position.z < zRange2){
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, zRange2);
        }
        if (transform.position.z > zRange){
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, zRange);
        }
    
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        forwardInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed * forwardInput);
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, turnSpeed * horizontalInput * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you declare public float tank outside the start function and initialize it in start function

Comment: You cannot use a modifier, in this case `public`, inside a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general: It is very unlikely that a compiler is broken in a way that it throws this kind of exception ;)

---

In `Start` you do

```
public float tank = GameObject.Find("tank").transform.localPosition.x;
```

You can not define a `public` field within the `Start` method (or any method in general to be exact).

Thus, before the `public` keyword the compiler expects a `}` to close the `Start` method. The rest is just follow-up errors caused by this first one.

The compiler will try to continue and "assume" the `}` was where it expects it thus your class `PlayerController` would already be closed with the next `}` after `public float tank ...` so the next error appears when hitting `public float horizontalInput` since it would require a `class`/`struct` around it. Therefore you a

> Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

---

You probably rather wanted

```
public float tank;

private void Start()
{
    tank = GameObject.Find("tank").transform.localPosition.x;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I'm new to C#, so that was a noob mistake. Thanks.